# Increase gRPC timeout in Go

Tags: go, grpc, grpc-go

There are a few gRPC calls that require the connection to remain connected for more than 5 minutes, which will be idle till the operation is complete.
I tried `keepalive` settings and even `context.WithTimeout()` but the gRPC connection gets timed out ater 5 minutes (code = Unknown desc = stream timeout")

How can i increase the idle timeout for such gRPC calls?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried,

```
clientDeadline := time.Now().Add(time.Duration(*deadlineMs) * time.Millisecond)
ctx, cancel := context.WithDeadline(ctx, clientDeadline)
```

like defined in official documentation of gRPC. Here is the https://grpc.io/blog/deadlines/ link.

Edit:

You can basically pass `Enforcement Policy` option to keep alive on the server-side as it is mentioned in the [source code](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-go/blob/2b6ff72f083d82762397ffcb7087a3be168c0919/keepalive/keepalive.go#L77),

```
// EnforcementPolicy is used to set keepalive enforcement policy on the
// server-side. Server will close connection with a client that violates this
// policy.
type EnforcementPolicy struct {
    // MinTime is the minimum amount of time a client should wait before sending
    // a keepalive ping.
    MinTime time.Duration // The current default value is 5 minutes.
    // If true, server allows keepalive pings even when there are no active
    // streams(RPCs). If false, and client sends ping when there are no active
    // streams, server will send GOAWAY and close the connection.
    PermitWithoutStream bool // false by default.
}
```

Comment: I used this with "grpc.DialContext()" where I set the deadline to 30 minutes, I can still see the stream timing out after 5 minutes.

Comment: You can apply `EnforcementPolicy` where it mentions 5mins as default value in the [link](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-go/blob/v1.56.0/keepalive/keepalive.go#L77)